# Multiple thenReturn not working properly in the Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm testing a method that call same method (`db.getData()`) twice. But I must return two different values.

```
       Mockito.when(db.someMethod()).thenReturn(valueOne).thenReturn(valueTwo);
```

Then I tried out multiple `thenReturn()`.

Unfortunately I'm getting only valueTwo for first & second `db.getData()` method call.

Comment: If you want it to return two different values for different calls, you can do it like this:
Mockito.when(db.someMethod()).thenReturn(valueOne);
db.someMethod();
Mockito.when(db.someMethod()).thenReturn(valueTwo);
db.someMethod();

Comment: @PiotrPytlik that's not correct, see: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html : "you can set different behavior for consecutive method calls. Last stubbing (e.g: thenReturn("foo")) determines the behavior of further consecutive calls.".

Comment: @Adriaan Sorry, got ahead of myself again. Yeah i was wrong...

Answer (score 3):

You are not showing a lot of context but here are some ideas:

- make sure db is really a mock object
- use the debugger to check if db.someMethod() is called twice as you expect
- You can also use `thenReturn(valueOne, valueTwo);` although that should not make  a difference

I suspect that your method is called more than twice and that you are missing the first invocation (which returns valueOne) and only looking at subsequent invocations (which will all return valueTwo).

See [the API](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html):

```
 //you can set different behavior for consecutive method calls.
 //Last stubbing (e.g: thenReturn("foo")) determines the behavior of further consecutive calls.
 when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
  .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
  .thenReturn("foo");
```

Comment: I did some mistake when creating valueOne and valueTwo (actually kind of a complex object). thenReturn(valueOne, valueTwo) & thenReturn(valueOne).thenReturn(valueTwo) both of them working properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably you are debugging and when you want to fetch the data of the breakPoint line, you are fetching from mock, so it will return one of it's `thenReturn()` parameters, so when you resume the test, it will test it with the second parameter.

I recommend you if you doubt it's working properly, one time fetch all `thenReturn()` items and after that you agree they're OK, start the test again with no tracing `thenReturn()` items.